# All the member paths give a 404 error

Tags: ee2, members, member-management

The title says it all really - I have built a custom login page using `{exp:member:login_form}` but when I create a link using `{path='member/forgot_password'}` and `{path='member/register'}` etc they just go to a 404 page.

Has anyone encountered this before? I am using Structure which I guess could mess with it but not sure. `{path='logout'}` works just fine. I am running EE 2.7.3.

Hope someone can help with this!

Comment: Is 'member' a template group on your site? And have you set your profile trigger word to something other than 'member' to avoid conflicts? (Members -> Member Preferences -> General Settings -> Profile Triggering Word)

Comment: Thanks! It was the trigger word - somehow got changed and I didn't even know it existed!

Comment: Bit weird though - its a random number - when I change it back to "member" and click save it just makes it a different random number. I don't have a template group called member either.

Comment: Are you using a config bootstrap (in particular the Focus Lab one)? That sets the member trigger to a random number just to get it out of the way from what I can tell. Search for "$env_config['profile_trigger'] = rand(0,time());" and change the rand function bit to "member".

Comment: An aside, if you keep your member stuff at /member/ then you'll run a higher risk of getting flooded with spam signups (this is just anecdotal, but I guess spammers know where the defaults are).

Comment: Yes - I noticed that just before you posted. I am indeed using Focus Lab's config. Thanks again.